# how could i change i initial value of NEWSEQUENTIALID() for sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, newsequentialid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSPm2.png)i was using uniqueidentifier colunm in my db and default value was newid()    i cahnge it to NEWSEQUENTIALID() how could i change the start value of it  to increasse the last one

Comment: show some sample data  and what does it mean by change initial value ?

Comment: What does this even mean? And why in the world do you care? If you are using newsequentialid the actual value should not matter at all.

Comment: i was using uniqueidentifier colunm in my db and default value was newid() i cahnge it to NEWSEQUENTIALID() how could i change the start value of it to increasse the last one

Comment: Well that clarified things.

Comment: Why do you need to change it? What could you possibly gain from that?

Comment: i work with two db(same db and same web application , user asked me to make it offline and online cuse network sometimes damage ) one is online other is offline and for some reasons i can't use replication in sqlserver so i use text file and write the procedure which done by programe and then run it in other side to get the data which created

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set initial value for newsequentialid(), See below example

```
create table t3 (id uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid(), idnum int)

insert into t3(id,idnum) values (newid(),10)
insert into t3(idnum) values (11),(12)

select * from t3
```

Even if you set different uniqueidentifier it will not continue from that.

Comment: so i cannot set initial value for newsequentialid()
thanks

Comment: Yes, but still not able to find msdn link for the same... You can refer further on this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cad8a4d7-714f-44a2-adb0-569655ac66e6/newsequentialid?forum=sqltools